# Gradle sync failed: Failed to create parent directory - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have facing the unexpected error in Android Studio and i can't able to run my app.

```
 'C:\Users\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.71\descriptors\com.android.tools.build\gradle' when creating directory 'C:\Users\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.71\descriptors\com.android.tools.build\gradle\3.6.3\fc7e8eef251519086b6ee9788cba4dd2'
```

There is something happen in Android studio and not able to run my app and App configuration have facing problem even.

Answer (score 1):

Delete these folder entirely at the path:

```
  C:\Users\.gradle\caches\
```

You are getting this error due to the corrupt caches stored in the studio.

Deleting and rebuilding the project again will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If delete caches not working, and if you are using local gradle in android studio. Delete your local gradle file and extract it again