# Ionic Capacitor App fails at Android build

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 5/React Project that I cannot create an Android production build with. When I run the build in Android studio, this is the error I receive. I cannot figure out anything that works, any help?

```
Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type DefaultConfigurationCache using DefaultConfigurationCache constructor as there is a problem with parameter #10 of type ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController.
   > Cannot create service of type ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController using ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController constructor as there is a problem with parameter #5 of type FileCollectionFingerprinterRegistry.
      > Cannot create service of type FileCollectionFingerprinterRegistry using method VirtualFileSystemServices$BuildSessionServices.createFileCollectionFingerprinterRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<FileCollectionFingerprinter>.
         > Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
            > Failed to create parent directory '/.gradle' when creating directory '/.gradle/6.8/fileHashes'

Thanks!
```

Comment: are you using plugins to get fingerprints or anything of the similar sort?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159848/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-create-parent-directory-android-studio

If it doesnt, it'd be good if i see your code if you wont mind